# Can I serve multiple domains with CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Can I implement the following behavior with AWS CloudFront:

```
https://{id}.example.com/ -> https://{id}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/
```

I want to make a CloudFront distribution that would simplify the API Gateway domains.

The `{id}` part is a placeholder, not a specific ID. I want `*.example.com` to match and redirect to `https://*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/` but with the `*` replaced by the part of the domain that matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the Origin to be as https://{id}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/ rather then giving new location (302) to Client. In this case, you can use lambda@edge to dynamically choose origin and pass the value you want.
Here is an example:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/

Whitelist the HOST header so you can parse the HOST header in the origin request function and add the parsed value in setting origin.

Comment: It works thank you! I spent the whole day on it though, not easy at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do by putting API gateway url with stage as Origin in CloudFront distribution.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain how I can match the placeholder in the domain and reuse the value of the placeholder in the origin? I am not sure that the question was clear enough, I have edited it to add more info.